# Windows Phone App 7.1 Change text of buttons from code behind

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have 5 buttons and they dynamically change by showing the names of days of the week omitting saturday and sunday. Can I use `Button.Content` to achieve this in Windows Phone?

Now I tried to run it, but when I want to go to the screen containing these buttons, it does not load but freezes and gives NO output.

What Am I missing or doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
        DateTime datetoday = DateTime.Today;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; )
        {

            if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                //it's saturday of sunday
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                    {
                        firstButton.Content = "Vrijdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                    {
                        firstButton.Content = "Donderdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                    {
                        firstButton.Content = "Woensdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                    {
                        firstButton.Content = "Dinsdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    {
                        firstButton.Content = "Maandag";
                    }
                }

                if (i == 1)
                {
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                    {
                        secondButton.Content = "Vrijdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                    {
                        secondButton.Content = "Donderdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                    {
                        secondButton.Content = "Woensdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                    {
                        secondButton.Content = "Dinsdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    {
                        secondButton.Content = "Maandag";
                    }
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                    {
                        thirdButton.Content = "Vrijdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                    {
                        thirdButton.Content = "Donderdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                    {
                        thirdButton.Content = "Woensdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                    {
                        thirdButton.Content = "Dinsdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    {
                        thirdButton.Content = "Maandag";
                    }
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                    {
                        fourthButton.Content = "Vrijdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                    {
                        fourthButton.Content = "Donderdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                    {
                        fourthButton.Content = "Woensdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                    {
                        fourthButton.Content = "Dinsdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    {
                        fourthButton.Content = "Maandag";
                    }
                }
                if (i == 4)
                {
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                    {
                        fifthButton.Content = "Vrijdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                    {
                        fifthButton.Content = "Donderdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                    {
                        fifthButton.Content = "Woensdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                    {
                        fifthButton.Content = "Dinsdag";
                    }
                    if (datetoday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    {
                        fifthButton.Content = "Maandag";
                    }
                }
                //currentWeek[i] = datetoday;
               // i++;
            }
           // datetoday = datetoday.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: brb, thedailywtf.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This freezes, because the loop runs forever - `i` never increments because you comented out the `i++` line.

Your code can be greatly simplified. You can achieve the same with:

```
var buttons = new [] {firstButton, secondButton, thirdButton, fourthButton, fifthButton};
var date = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var button in buttons)
{
    while(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    button.Content = date.ToString("dddd");
    date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

or, if you need names in specific language, use:

```
date.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("pl-PL"));
```